# What's the basic technique for long braising of pork?

Tags: cooking-time, pork, slow-cooking, boiling

I boiled 1kg chunk of pork 12 hours:

- first boiling 45 min
- 8 h at low heat
- 45 min boiling
- low heat now some hours

I am not sure if this was a good strategy.

---

I know there's no single "right" way, but what's the rough basic technique here? And what's the maximum time I can reasonably cook it?

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of answer you are expecting here. A recipe for boiling pork? Asking what is the max time you can leave the meat in the water?

Comment: @rumtscho Yes, max time and how it should be done. I am so newbie in cooking the pork

Comment: "How it should be done" is very close to a recipe request, it should be done the way your recipe tells you to do it. As for the max time, it is very close to http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/25850/what-is-the-lowest-and-slowest-way-i-can-bake-pork-ribs - that is a question about the oven, but there isn't really that much difference with these methods.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why boiling is involved...  Are you cooking in oven or slow cooker?  You can just put the seasoned meat into the slow cooker and turn it on.  Or if in oven are you cooking at 225F or 100C how long depends on what cut of meat.  If one with lots of fat, like shoulder or ribs, it will hold up to long cooking.  Eight hours isn't too long.  I cook most organ meats like heart and tongue in slow cooker overnight.  Please ask follow up questions and provide more details...